# JHipster how to get yeoman prompt input without using props?

Tags: jhipster, yeoman

Suppose I have an array that contains an object in yeoman prompt:

```
 const getDatabaseName = [
        {
            type: 'input',
            name: 'dbName',
            message: 'Please enter your database name:',
            default: 'testdb',
            store: true
        }
 ]
```

I know we could use props.dbName to retrieve user input for this object. But, how would I get the input using standard object call?

I tried this: getDatabaseName[0].dbName, but it's undefined.

Comment: See yeoman doc, https://yeoman.io/authoring/user-interactions.html  you indicated only how you declare prompt not how you run it with something like `this.answers = await this.prompt(getDabatabseName)`and then `answers.dbName`

Comment: Is it possible to get the input without using async function?

Comment: As doc says: "The prompt method is asynchronous and returns a promise"